# How can I use equalTo for setting data(not finding data) javascript (Parse Platform)

Tags: javascript, react-native, parse-platform

Can we use `equalTo` for set data in database (not find data) in parse platform ?

It's not on documents

Answer (score 0):

No. The `equalTo()` function only exists in Parse.Query instances for searching data. In order to set data, you need to use the `set()` function existent in Parse.Object instances. It would be something like the code below:

## Updating a Single Object

```
const GameScore = Parse.Object.extend('GameScore');
const query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
const gameScore = await query.get('xWMyZ4YEGZ');
gameScore.set('score', 1337);
gameScore.set('playerName', 'Sean Plott');
gameScore.set('cheatMode', false);
gameScore.set('skills', ['pwnage', 'flying']);
await gameScore.save();
```

## Updating Multiple Objects

```
const GameScore = Parse.Object.extend('GameScore');
const query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo('skills', 'flying');
const gameScores = await query.find();
gameScores.forEach(gameScore => {
  gameScore.set('score', 1337);
  gameScore.set('playerName', 'Sean Plott');
  gameScore.set('cheatMode', false);
  gameScore.set('skills', ['pwnage', 'flying']);
});
await Parse.Object.saveAll(gameScores);
```

You can find more information about how to find and save objects [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#objects)

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but I don't want set data to a particular object I wan't set for example for all my objects in my class which their skills = flying . not to set one by one Sorry for my bad questioning!!

Comment: I've just edited the response with an example on how to update multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

Using The code example you can also save like this:
(https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Object.html#save)

```
const GameScore = Parse.Object.extend('GameScore');
const query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
const gameScore = await query.get('xWMyZ4YEGZ');
await gameScore.save({
  score: 1337,
  playerName: 'Sean Plott',
  cheatMode: false,
  skills: ['pwnage', 'flying'],
});
```